# Change font size at runtime with slider for entire Java Swing application with Nimbus L&F (Linux)

Tags: java, swing, font-size, look-and-feel

The following approach does not work for me. I don't know if it is due to the fact that I'm using Nimbus L&F, or maybe it is because I'm not redrawing the components properly after the fact, or maybe it is because my app is a Netbeans SingleFrameApplication (boy, do I regret that decision) or maybe I have overlooked something obvious. I have read a couple dozen posts on this topic and I have experimented with a lot of various approaches but I have not found anything that will accomplish the task.

I would like the font size changes to apply to any components already created as well as any that get created subsequently (such as new dialogs, etc.).

(I plan to save the font size to the application's properties so the next instance will start up with the chosen font size. I would also like to implement themes -- such as for users with low vision -- so maybe there is an overall better approach.)

```
public static void adjustGlobalFontSize(Float percentChange) {

    Enumeration keySet = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keySet.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object key = keySet.nextElement();
        Object value = UIManager.get(key);
        if (value instanceof Font) {
            Font f = (Font)value;
            Float sizef = f.getSize2D() * percentChange;
            int size = Math.round(sizef);               
            FontUIResource resf = new FontUIResource(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), size);
            UIManager.put(key, resf);
        }
    }
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(MyApp.getApplication().getMainFrame());

}
```

EDIT 1: I switched from Nimbus LAF to the GTK LAF, as suggested in the comments. I tested both the code above and the code offered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907047/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-in-the-swing-gtk-lookandfeel) (which is essentially identical).

In both cases, the fonts are not changed as I would expect. A few selected fonts in a few controls are changed, but they are changed in a very strange way -- for example, items in a combobox list are magnified only when mousing over them.

So the issue is not related just to Nimbus LAF. In fact, maybe GTK is worse...

For reference, here is the output of the code in the question linked above.

```
                 Menu.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
       ScrollPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      SliderThumb.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
     ColorChooser.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
        PopupMenu.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
            Panel.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
            Table.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      DesktopIcon.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         ComboBox.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
 FormattedTextField.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      RadioButton.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
  InternalFrame.titleFont :                   java.awt.Font[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=bold,size=12]
             Tree.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
           Button.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
 PopupMenuSeparator.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         TextArea.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
InternalFrameTitlePane.font :javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      ArrowButton.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         Viewport.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
   ScrollBarThumb.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
       EditorPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
   ScrollBarTrack.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
        ScrollBar.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      ProgressBar.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      FileChooser.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
     ToggleButton.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
          ToolBar.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         MenuItem.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
           defaultFont : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         RootPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         TextPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
           Slider.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
          MenuBar.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
             List.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
 CheckBoxMenuItem.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
        SplitPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
        Separator.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
          Spinner.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
          ToolTip.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
    PasswordField.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
        TextField.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
       TabbedPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
       OptionPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
     TitledBorder.font :                    java.awt.Font[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=bold,size=12]
            Label.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      SliderTrack.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      TableHeader.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
RadioButtonMenuItem.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
         CheckBox.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
    InternalFrame.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
      DesktopPane.font : javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=DejaVu Sans,name=DejaVu Sans,style=plain,size=12]
```

EDIT 2: Additional info: If I don't try to make the change at runtime, but instead invoke the method at application startup before any GUI elements are created, I have some measure of success. Most fonts are scaled as desired. The major exceptions are buttons and radio buttons and text areas. That's strange because all are listed as being updated in the code above. Other components such as ComboBoxes, JLables, and much more, get updated font sizes.

As as first step, I guess I should focus on getting everything working in this manner (i.e., changed only prior to startup). Any ideas why not all fonts are updated?

Comment: If you don't know if the problem is the Nimbus LAF, then try the code using the default LAF.

Comment: @camickr, my app requires the Nimbus LAF. For some reason, certain UI controls (e.g., sliders) not not rendered properly with the default LAF. That's an entire issue unto itself that we have not been able to resolve for a long time. It might be a Linux thing or it might be something else. After a lot of debugging, we finally resolved it by changing the LAF. Before I plunge into reverting the LAF and open that can of worms again, I am hoping for some feedback here.

Comment: I didn't ask you to revert the LAF. I asked you to narrow down the problem. We now have 3 variables, the code, the LAF and the OS. So does the code work with the default LAF? If so then we know the problem is the Nimbus LAF. If it doesn't work, then it could be the OS or the code. If which case you need to post an SSCCE so people can test the code on different OS to see what happens.

Comment: I ruled out Nimbus LAF. As far as testing the code, I have seen many posted examples of almost identical code using UIManager.getDefaults. I think what I need now is either a suggestion of a completely different approach or some discussion/help of what I might be doing wrong in terms of updating the GUI after the code runs. All I am doing right now is: MyApp.getApplication().getMainFrame().pack();

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Metal LAF which I consider to be the most stable. You still haven't posted a SSCCE so I can't test the code on a Windows machine. We still haven't ruled out that the problem is Linux or whether the problem is your code!!!