# Swing and GTK font

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I have write a little GUI with java Swing. But i have some little problems with the default look and feel using `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`

[image]

As you can see the menus and the buttons doesn't have the same font of the other application in my Desktop (In the picture Eclipse and Nautilus), I'm using GTK on Gnome2.

Meanwhile using the relative look and feel on windows there are not differences:

[image]

The font look identical.

How is it possible this? Which parameters can I modify to edit the font look on GTK?

Answer (score 0):

You should let the System decide which L&F to use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

In your above image you are using Ubuntu with Unity (I guess?), but [Unity does not use GTK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16253/what-gui-toolkit-will-ubuntu-unity-use) but [Nux](https://launchpad.net/nux).

Another way to create a native Look and Feel is the using the [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) (Standard Widget Toolkit) that provides you with system dependent libraries for Windows, Linux and OSX, so that the graphical elements in your program use the actual native elements from those systems. But I have to warn you, it may not be that easy (and sometimes even weird and annoying :) ) to use, because you cannot use *any* Swing components. So maybe that's not worth the trouble – it's for you to decide.

Comment: This instruction gave me the same result of setting `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel` as look and feel.
P.S. I'm using gtk on Gnome2

Comment: Hm, then I am out of ideas. I just tried this example of oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic and added a menu so I could see what it looks like in my Ubuntu. But there was no difference in the menu. Is it possible that you somehow use other settings for Java programs in Ubuntu – like by using Compiz?

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting defaults for the fonts on components after setting your look and feel.

```
UIManager.put("Menu.font", new FontUIResource(your_desired_font));
UIManager.put("Button.font", new FontUIResource(your_desired_font));
```

Windows L&F is using by default `new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);`

Answer (score 0):

For GTK, set the font standard by UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults() does not work... then I found a hack via reflection that works, you can find it here in response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31345102/3757320